# SQL compare two columns with different cases

Tags: sql, compare, case, multiple-columns

Okay i will rephrase it.

I have a list of servers in a table with a column that shows their version. I need to check if they are up to date.
If the version is less than the latest servicepack and greater than the first version, it needs an update. Becuase there exists version from 2012. 2010, 2008, 2005 and so on.

Here is a link where it list the version, wich is the first and the latest.
http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.dk/

my code so far is:

```
SELECT SrvName, Name, SQL-Version, ServicePck FROM dbo.SQLsrvVersion
(CASE
WHEN (dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version < 12.00.2000 AND dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version > 11.00.9120) THEN 'Needs update'
WHEN (dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version < 11.00.5058 AND dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version > 11.00.2100) THEN 'Needs update'
WHEN (dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version < 10.50.4000 AND dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version > 10.50.1600) THEN 'Needs update'
WHEN (dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version < 10.00.5500 AND dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version > 10.00.1600) THEN 'Needs update'
WHEN (dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version < 9.00.5000 AND dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version > 9.00.1399) THEN 'Needs update'
WHEN (dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version < 8.00.2039 AND dbo.SQLsrvVersion.SQL-Version > 8.00.194) THEN 'Needs update'
END)
```

Comment: (1) Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  (2) What is "program 1", "program 2"?  (3) What are the rules for doing the match?  (4) What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question, and the database i am using is SQL

Comment: "SQL" is a language, somewhat standardized, for processing data.  Databases are products, such as DB2, Informix, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, Sybase, Teradata, and the like.